# Reduce Memory footprint if possible using Ado.NET Adapter

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the need to synchronize a mobile database with the main database one. The idea is the following. I've got a REST service that accepts in input the name of the table I need to sync (with a DateTime, since the next time the data exchanged will only be the delta from last sync to the date I pass).

In the current implementation (since I want to be as more generic as possible) is the following

```
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM XXX", connection))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())

                    {
                        ds.WriteXml(memoryStream, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

                        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

//just for test                        File.WriteAllText("c:\\temp\\XXX.txt", data);
                    }
                }
```

Now for a table that on disk is around 256MB I got a memory footprint of 1GB.
Any suggestion on how to reduce the memory footprint?

Thanks

Comment: is your entire DB around 1GB? if so then the number makes sense since your DB engine will attempt to keep as much data as possible in memory. If you dont want that to happen you can restrict the amount of Ram your DB engine can use in your DB's settings. (vary by different engine)

Comment: It sounds like this should be solved via a Distributed DB approach to begin with. It seems like you implemented replication the hard way. As for the memory footprint, it is totally normal for such adapters to need a lot of RAM. Actually twice as much as the data it retreives, as they retreive the data and then translate it to a Langauge specific format like a Datatable. Of course string interning can help a ton if you got a lot of text data.

Answer (score 0):

Options to reduce memory:

1. don't load the entire table; add a `WHERE` clause, perhaps using paging or similar
2. don't use `DataTable` - it is *not your friend* for efficiency; if you just need the data, consider POCO types, perhaps with any ORM of your choice
3. if you are trying to write to a file, don't use a `MemoryStream`: write directly to the `FileStream` so you don't need an additional copy of everything; there's also no need for that `ToArray()` - even if you use `MemoryStream`, prefer `GetBuffer()` and limit to `.Length`; or use `StringWriter`

Answer (score 0):

I explain you.. since I need to load (and at the first time I need to fully load around 30 tables) I neednto have the whole dataset. I know poco are better but I would have to create 30 POCOs and have to manually pwrform the insert on the client side. this way I load the dataset and do a bulkinsert

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [the docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.writexml?view=netframework-4.8#examples), you will see the output of a very simple  example datatable. XML is just creating a huge overhead based on opening and closing xml-tags.

From the link

This:

```
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "Mary" }); 
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Andy" }); 
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "Peter" }); 
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, "Russ" });
```

Results in

```
 <Table1>  
     <ID>1</ID>. 
     <Name>Mary</Name>    
</Table1>    
<Table1>  
     <ID>2</ID>  
     <Name>Andy</Name>   
</Table1>   
<Table1>  
     <ID>3</ID>  
     <Name>Peter</Name>   
</Table1>   
<Table1>      
    <ID>4</ID>     
    <Name>Russ</Name>  
</Table1>
```

What I want to say is that for this small example a source content of 17 chars and 4 integers results in 156 chars. This should explain why a memory footprint of 1GB for a database of 256MB should be expected.

Comment: I know this, but I don't want to perform the 1-1 mapping for each entity I've

Comment: Updated answer to explain it further.